# Card.Color cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, types

In this code i have a problem with error: Card.Color cannot be resolved to a type. I´m beginner in java programming so if someone can explain me what is going wrong here i will be very gladly.

```
public class Card extends java.lang.Object 
{
    private  int value;
    private Card.Color c;

    public static enum Color 
    {
        CLUBS("C"), DIAMONDS("D"), HEARTS("H"), SPADES("S");

        private final String c;

        private Color(String c)
        {
            this.c = c;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return c;
        }
    }


    public Card(Card.Color c, int value)
    {
        this.c = c;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int value()
    {
        return value;
    }


    public Color color()
    {
        return c;
    }


}
```

Comment: Not the problems, but `extends java.lang.Object` and `static` in `static enum` are unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i´m trying to compile it in eclipse. I have this error on : public Card(Card.Color c, int value) and public Color color()

Comment: Modify any occurrence of `Card.Color` to `Color`. What were you trying to do ?

Comment: That doesn´t change anything still same error on same places.

Comment: That code works fine. Either try a different IDE or update it if possible. (works online as well http://ideone.com/GcmwuA)

Comment: So its eclipse based error ? there are more errors like cannot make static reference to the non-static field on  private final String c;